# Is there anyway to force jquery dialog vertical scrollbar to top?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, scrolltop, vertical-scrolling

I have a jquery dialog and I am opening it up with this code:

$("#myDialog").dialog("open").css("maxHeight", window.innerHeight - 150);

I have that css() at the end to make sure the dialog is not longer than the current users window and if so to cut it off and create a vertical scroll bar.

That works fine but now I want to force the vertical scrollbar to the top but I can't seem to get it to work.  I have tried put this after the line above:

```
    $("#myDialog").scrollTop(0);

    $("#myDialog").scrollTop();
```

and I have tried this as well:

```
    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 'auto',
        open: function () {
            $(this).scrollTop(0);
        },
```

but nothing seems to force the vertical scroll bar to the top after the dialog opens.

Comment: what do you mean by  `force the vertical scrollbar to the top`

Answer (score 3):

add these two option to your dialog as follows, and by default your scroll will be on top:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
        maxHeight: window.innerHeight - 15,
        overflow:'scroll'
});
```

use something like:

```
<div id="clickme">click me</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>ipt Library. Whether you're building highly interactive web applications or you just need to add a date picker to a form control, jQuery UI is the perfect choice.
    jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface jQuery UI is a curated set.</p>
</div>

<script>
$( "#clickme" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    event.preventDefault();
});

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,   
    maxHeight: window.innerHeight - 15,
    overflow:'scroll',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});

</script>
```

check my code in http://jsfiddle.net/fmqyw889/1/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work ..  If I do this, I no longer see the vertical scrollbar at all